# How do I combine JSON objects with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, oracle, vue.js

I've been searching for days and days, but can't seem to find the answer to this.

Let's say I have a database that contains information regarding how many kilos of ingredients are used in each room of a house, depending on the season of the year, and the chef that uses them, though the chef is only used in the "WHERE" clause. This information is collected by a web application (not developed by me) and stored in its database. I am trying to extend the application by creating some new pages and reports, mainly just for displaying info. The SQL (Oracle) output is as follows (I've omitted several columns, not of interest):

```
| ROOM_ID | SEASON | ING_S1 | ING_S2 | ING_S3 |
| 1234567 |   1    |   35   |        |        |
| 1234567 |   2    |        |   24   |        |
| 1234567 |   3    |        |        |   15   |
| 2233445 |   2    |        |   60   |        |
| 2233445 |   3    |        |        |   41   |
```

The ingredient columns are coming from a really complicated series of joins needed to extract them from other tables within the application.

This web application allows me to, within HTML, put this into a JSON, and I've managed to make it look like this:

```
"1234567" : {
    "roomName" : "blabla",
    "season" : "1",
    "ingredientsS1" : "35",
    "ingredientsS2" : "",
    "ingredientsS3" : "",
},
"1234567" : {
    "roomName" : "blabla",
    "season" : "2",
    "ingredientsS1" : "",
    "ingredientsS2" : "24",
    "ingredientsS3" : "",
},
"1234567" : {
    "roomName" : "blabla",
    "season" : "3",
    "ingredientsS1" : "",
    "ingredientsS2" : "",
    "ingredientsS3" : "15",
},
```

And so on....

What I'd like to see is:

```
"1234567" : {
    "roomName" : "blabla",
    "ingredientsS1" : "35",
    "ingredientsS2" : "24",
    "ingredientsS3" : "15",
},
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to merge the properties of each object defined by the roomID! I've tried to rework the query a million ways to see if I could merge all of the results into one row (listagg and so on) and thus have the web application create only one JSON object, I've tried to look at solutions using jQuery and plain JavaScript... no dice.

I'm also going to start using Vue.js to add some more features to the page, but I can't seem to find any solution on that route either.

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: Provide the script you have so far, and we'll help make that happen

Comment: *"'I've managed to make it look like this"*, no, you can not have more than one key with the same name.

Comment: Does not the console show you an error? Javascript object can not contain same key to the object. Is that the real response from your server?

Comment: What the server does is that it allows you, using a tag special to the app, to run an SQL query and then output the data as rows of text, placing the fields wherever you'd like within that same row.

Nina, Christoforus - Of course it's not valid JSON as there are multiple keys with the same name, sorry - what I should have said is that the web application allows me to create a text document that looks like the above. When I load the text doc in the browser, that's what shows up - I haven't used it in JS because it's invalid.

@LGSon by script, do you mean query? Thanks!!

Comment: If you can output the data as an array of objects, this would be possible to solve.

Comment: @RustyDev I can output the data in any form onto a text document, given the limitation that I can only deal with the data row by row (i.e. I can tell the application where to put each field with variables/tags, but these variables only work within each row)

Comment: please give tha data, you get from the db by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get the data as an object from the data base, you could iterate the objects and take the properties for new object.

For assigning a value, you could take `SEASON` for addressing the related ingredients.

```js
var data = [
        { ROOM_ID: 1234567, SEASON: 1, ING_S1: 35, ING_S2: null, ING_S3: null },
        { ROOM_ID: 1234567, SEASON: 2, ING_S1: null, ING_S2: 24, ING_S3: null },
        { ROOM_ID: 1234567, SEASON: 3, ING_S1: null, ING_S2: null, ING_S3: 15 },
        { ROOM_ID: 2233445, SEASON: 2, ING_S1: null, ING_S2: 60, ING_S3: null },
        { ROOM_ID: 2233445, SEASON: 3, ING_S1: null, ING_S2: null, ING_S3: 41 }
    ],
    result = {};

data.forEach(({ ROOM_ID, SEASON, ING_S1, ING_S2, ING_S3 }) => {
    result[ROOM_ID] = result[ROOM_ID] || { roomName: 'blabla', ingredientsS1: '', ingredientsS2: '', ingredientsS3: '' };
    result[ROOM_ID]['ingredientsS' + SEASON] = [ING_S1, ING_S2, ING_S3][SEASON - 1];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh my God! This is wonderful!! You're a genius!!! I adapted the code to the real data (which, I am sorry, I could not publish due to compliance laws) and it works great so far! THANK YOU!!!

Where can I learn more about what you did?